# why does an automomorphism of a vector space have an eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

"Let f be an automorphism of a complex space $V \ne O$. Then f has an eigenvalue."
 Could you explain why this is true? Thanks.
edit: V has a finite dimension

Comment: I feel like you need the assumption that $V$ is finite for this to be true.

Comment: What do you know about polynomials over $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: An eigenvalue is a root of the characteristic polynomial of $f$. But a complex polynomial always has a root.

Comment: carmichael561 That they always have a root?

Comment: @Kryštof - yes. That is the fundamental theorem of algebra: Every polynomial over the complex numbers has a root.